# Share URL from website to LinkedIn in app for iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, share, linkedin-api

On my website, I've a "Share to linkedin" button. 
It goes to `https://inkedin.com/shareArticle?url=URL` and shares just the way it should, not problem.

When I am on a Android phone and have the LinkedIn app installedd it opens up the share dialog within the app and I get the "share post" in app.

But on iPhone it doesn't.
I replace `https://` with `linkedin://` and it opens the LinkedIn app but navigates to home in the LinkedIn app and not the share dialog box as it does on Android.

I want to have the same behaviour on iPhone (iOS) with LinkedIn app installed as on Android.

If I go to addthis.com and use their [LinkedIn button example](http://www.addthis.com/social-buttons/linkedin-button) on an iPhone it does open the LinkedIn app in the right "share post" dialog window.

I'm not sure if the `shareArticle` path in the URL are correct when it comes to LinkedIn app for iOS.

I've made a [CodePen for testing](https://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/PKVZXx) it with a normal "shareArticle" link and a specific `linkedin://` share link